# Fetch markers on Google Map with the moving of map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an android application, where I want to display some markers on the google map. I want to fetch markers when user moves the map through, and also I'm having huge number of markers stored in a database based on location. To get markers I have to request by the current middle location on map-camera.

So what I'm asking is, is there a better criteria for requesting for markers, based on the movement of user and current zoom level of the map. Here I need some optimization such as I don't need to request for same marker again.

> Note: The key point here is not to make unwanted requests for fetching markers and not to keep higher number of markers in client side memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current middle camera location  by overriding GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveCanceledListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener.

```
@Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        double nextlatitude = mGoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.getCenter().latitude;
        double nextlongitude = mGoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.getCenter().longitude;

        System.out.println("Location Next : "+nextlatitude+"  "+nextlongitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraMoveCanceled() {
//        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Camera movement canceled.",
//                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraMove() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {
//        if (reason == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE) {
//            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The user gestured on the map.",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        } else if (reason == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener
//                .REASON_API_ANIMATION) {
//            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The user tapped something on the map.",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        } else if (reason == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener
//                .REASON_DEVELOPER_ANIMATION) {
//            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The app moved the camera.",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        }
    }
```

and you can get the current zoom level by this:

```
map.getCameraPosition().zoom
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to show multiple marker according to current map position so first of all you need to get center position of google map and get the latitude and longitude of that position so add this camera change listener

```
View viewMap=mapFragment.getView();
googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                Point point=new Point();
                point.set((int)viewMap.getX(),(int)viewMap.getY());
                latLng=googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.getCenter();
            }
        });
```

This will show the current center position lat long of map .but returns more lat and long. so you need when google map idle call the api according to current position and fatch record,use this code.

```
googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraIdle() {
            Log.e("bug"," location is "+latLng.latitude+ ", "+latLng.longitude);
           //call api
        }
    });
```

after getting record first clear the google map so that remove all added marker from map.
googleMap.clear();
and add new marker on the map.

This would help you,  its help me.